# element.style margin bottom

Tags: wordpress, css

How can I remove this 85px

```
element.style {margin-bottom: 85px;}
```

from [here on home page](http://agro.websitedesign.ge/), below the wrapper and content area?

Maybe it belongs to visual composer plugin or to theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Wrapper > div {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

add this rule into your template main CSS file or check is there your HTML code may be added from there

Comment: I marked your answers as useful. If I understood correctly what you meant... :)

Comment: there will be a tick below your the vote sections you need to check on it and then accept this is as a best answer  http://prntscr.com/fp24zf  check image LOL

Answer (score 0):

It's hardcoded on the element

```
<div id="Content" style="margin-bottom: 85px;">
```

You need to remove it from the template or the JavaScript that adds this rule. Alternatively you can use `margin-bottom: 0 !important`